# What do I need to learn to embed matplotlib in a Rails application?

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, matplotlib

I use Python for data analysis. I am learning Ruby on Rails for building a web application. I have a good grasp of Ruby, HTML, CSS, and am now about to finish Hartl's The Rails Tutorial. I don't know much JavaScript (yet).

What are the technologies needed to embed matplotlib plots in a Rails application? I'd like to have a dashboard of plots that I consider important, and that are the result of number crunching in Python.

Comment: Honestly, if it's a rails application, you'd probably be better off with a non-python solution.  Setting everything up to have ruby call python to generate a png to send back is going to be a bit of a pain.  Furthermore, if you're wanting browser-based graphics, there are a lot of fantastic javascript plotting libraries out there that can be used effectively with relatively little knowledge of JS.  I'd recommend that approach instead of trying to shoehorn matplotlib into a rails application.

Comment: I'm interested in the power that I have when I use Python libraries like Pandas, NumPy, SciPy and scikit-learn. Plotting into matplotlib is actually the result of using these other libraries. Actually, I would not only like to have a png, but some kind of applet where I can tinker with the plot, with calls to Python libraries.

Comment: Would it be easier to use Django? I'm using Ruby on Rails to learn web development, so I will go through with this specific learning path. But afterwards, perhaps I can switch to Django. I don't know, technically speaking, what it is that makes it easier or not to interact with Python.